# How to replace a line with multiple lines in multiline format?

Tags: sed

There is a similar question on SO, however, the provided answer is all done in one line. For readability purposes I would like the solution on multiple lines:

This is what I tried although as append:

```
sed -i '/home_server localhost {/a\
home_server example-coa {\
        type = coa\
        ipaddr = 127.0.0.1\
        port = 3799\
        secret = '"${SECRET}"'\
        coa {\
                irt = 2\
                mrt = 16\
                mrc = 5\
                mrd = 30\
        }\
}\
home_server localhost {\
' /etc/freeradius/3.0/proxy.conf
```

This is an example of APPEND, it works, but I need to do a replace.
I would like to replace `home_server localhost {` with the above.

I'm literally trying to add a block above it so that it will look like this at the end:

```
home_server example-coa {
...
}
home_server localhost {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just **insert**? E.g

```bash
sed -i '/home_server localhost {/i\
home_server example-coa {\
        type = coa\
        ipaddr = 127.0.0.1\
        port = 3799\
        secret = '"${SECRET}"'\
        coa {\
                irt = 2\
                mrt = 16\
                mrc = 5\
                mrd = 30\
        }\
}\
' /etc/freeradius/3.0/proxy.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
cat <<! | sed '/home_server localhost {/e cat /dev/stdin' file
home_server example-coa {
    type = coa
    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
    port = 3799
    secret = '"${SECRET}"'
    coa {
            irt = 2
            mrt = 16
            mrc = 5
            mrd = 30
    }
}
!
```

Use the `e` command to place a here-document in the output stream of a sed command.